# MultipleBinding for a WPF Converter... when does ConvertBack get called?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, updatesourcetrigger

I have a ComboBox with a set of values. The selected value is determined by a Converter with a multiple two-way binding. When the user changes the value in the ComboBox, I expected the ConvertBack method to get called and change the values of the two properties used in the Multiple Binding, but this doesn't happen, even when the ComboBox loses focus. I tried to change the UpdateSourceTrigger property to "LosesFocus" but this is apparently not valid for a MultipleBinding. How do I get the ConvertBack method to fire, either when the value changes or when the control loses focus? Either will work for my purposes.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DescriptionList}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="Description" IsEnabled="{Binding EditMode}">
    <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DescriptionConverter}">
            <Binding Path="PersonRow.DescriptionType" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
            <Binding Path="PersonRow.DescriptionSuccessful" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add `Mode="TwoWay"` to your `<MultiBinding>`.

Comment: I tried adding Mode="TwoWay" to the MutiBinding tag, but the ConvertBack method still does not fire.

Comment: @jpaull I'd also remove the `Mode` and `UpdateSourceTrigger` attributes from the sub-bindings. You could try adding `UpdateSourceTrigger` on the `MultiBinding` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Jay's suggestion hinted me in the right direction. I also added an UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" to the MultiBinding tag and was able to fire the event.